# Let $T\in M_m(\mathbb{C})$ with $r(T)=1$. Is it true that $\lim \frac{\lVert T^{n+1}\rVert}{\lVert T^n\rVert}=1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrices, functional-analysis, analysis

Here the norm $\lVert\cdot\rVert$ denotes the operator norm. If $T$ is a Jordan matrix with spectral radius $r(T)=1$, then I am able to prove that $\frac{\lVert T^{n+1}\rVert}{\lVert T^n\rVert}\to1$. For general $T$, $T=PJP^{-1}$ where $J$ is the Jordan cannonical form for $T$. Then $\lVert T^n\rVert\le \lVert P\rVert\lVert P^{-1}\rVert\lVert J^n\rVert$ and also $\lVert J^n\rVert\le \lVert P\rVert\lVert P^{-1}\rVert\lVert T^n\rVert$.

Then $$ \frac{\lVert T^{n+1}\rVert}{\lVert T^n\rVert}\le (\lVert P\rVert\lVert P^{-1}\rVert)^2  \frac{\lVert J^{n+1}\rVert}{\lVert J^n\rVert}\implies\limsup \frac{\lVert T^{n+1}\rVert}{\lVert T^n\rVert}\le (\lVert P\rVert\lVert P^{-1}\rVert)^2$$

Also,
$$\left|\frac{\lVert T^{n+1}\rVert}{\lVert T^n\rVert}-1\right|\le\frac{|\lVert T^{n+1}\rVert-\lVert T^n\rVert|}{\lVert T^n\rVert}\le \frac{\lVert T^{n+1}-T^n\rVert}{\lVert T^n\rVert}\le \lVert T-I\rVert$$

Can we say anything about the convergence of the sequence $\frac{\lVert T^{n+1}\rVert}{\lVert T^n\rVert}$? It may not be $1$, but does it converge at least?

Can anyone help me with any idea? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. It's $T$.

Comment: If the limit exists it must be equal $r(T).$

Answer (score 4):

The answer is that it doesn't need to converge. You can take $$T = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & -1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\-1 & 1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\2 & -1\end{pmatrix}$$

that is, $T=PDP^{-1}$ with $P=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and $D=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$.

Then for $n$ even, $T^n = PD^2P^{-1}=I_2$ so $||T^n||=1$, but for $n$ odd, $T^n = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\2 & -1\end{pmatrix}$, and you can verify by hand that this matrix has operator norm $1+\sqrt{2}$ (the actual value doesn't even matter).

Consequently, the ratio $\frac{||T^{n+1}||}{||T^n||}$ alternates between the values $1+\sqrt{2}$ and $\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{2}}$, so it doesn't converge.

Answer (score 3):

It is true if all dominant eigenvalues of $T$ are the same.

Suppose this is the case. Let $\lambda$ be the dominant eigenvalue. Since $\frac{\|T^{n+1}\|}{\|T^n\|}=\frac{\|(\overline{\lambda}T)^{n+1}\|}{\|(\overline{\lambda}T)^n\|}$, we may assume that $\lambda=1$. If this eigenvalue is semi-simple, then $T=P(I\oplus B)P^{-1}$ for some invertible matrix $P$ and for some matrix $B$ whose spectral radius is strictly smaller than $1$. Therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty}T^n=P(I\oplus0)P^{-1}$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\|T^{n+1}\|}{\|T^n\|}=1$.

If the eigenvalue $1$ is not semi-simple, let $m$ be the largest size of its Jordan blocks in the Jordan form of $T$. Then $T=P\big((I+N)\oplus B)P^{-1}$, where $P$ is invertible, $N$ is a non-empty direct sum of nilpotent $m\times m$ Jordan blocks, and $B$ is a direct sum of Jordan blocks of smaller sizes for the eigenvalue $1$ and also Jordan blocks of various sizes for other eigenvalues. Since
$$
(I+N)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\binom{n}{k}N^k
$$
and $\binom{n}{k}\left/\binom{n}{m-1}\right. =o(1)$ whenever $0\le k<m-1$, we have
$$
T^n
=\binom{n}{m-1}P\left[\left(N^{m-1}+o(1)\right)\oplus o(1)\right]P^{-1}.
$$
Therefore
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\|T^{n+1}\|}{\|T^n\|}
&=\frac{\binom{n+1}{m-1}
\left\|P\left[\left(N^{m-1}+o(1)\right)\oplus o(1)\right]P^{-1}\right\|}
{\binom{n}{m-1}
\left\|P\left[\left(N^{m-1}+o(1)\right)\oplus o(1)\right]P^{-1}\right\|}\\
&=\frac{\binom{n+1}{m-1}
\left\|P\left[\left(N^{m-1}+o(1)\right)\oplus o(1)\right]P^{-1}\right\|
\left/\left\|P\left[N^{m-1}\oplus 0\right]P^{-1}\right\|\right.}
{\binom{n}{m-1}
\left\|P\left[\left(N^{m-1}+o(1)\right)\oplus o(1)\right]P^{-1}\right\|
\left/\left\|P\left[N^{m-1}\oplus 0\right]P^{-1}\right\|\right.}.\\
\end{aligned}
$$
As $\lim_{n\to\infty}\binom{n+1}{m-1}\left/\binom{n}{m-1}\right. =\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1}{n-m+2}=1$, we obtain $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\|T^{n+1}\|}{\|T^n\|}=1$.

**Remark.** The sufficient condition that all dominant eigenvalues of $T$ are the same can be slightly weakened as follows. Suppose that $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_s$ are the distinct dominant eigenvalues of $T$. In the Jordan form of $T$, if some Jordan block for some $\lambda_i$ is larger than the Jordan blocks for all other $\lambda_j$s (with $j\ne i$), then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\|T^{n+1}\|}{\|T^n\|}=1$ by a similar argument to the above.

Comment: Can you explain when you write $T^n=\binom{n}{m-1}P[(N^{m-1}+o(1)]P^{-1}$ how do you get $B^n$ to be $o(1)$? And observing your solution, I feel like the sequence $\frac{\lVert T^{n+1}\rVert}{\lVert T^n\rVert}$ is Cesaro summable. Is it true?

Comment: And can we say that for large n, $\lVert P[(N^{m-1}+o(1))\oplus o(1)]P^{-1}\rVert=1$?

Comment: @DeltaEpsilon $B^n$ is not necessarily $o(1)$. It is $B^n/\binom{n}{m-1}$ that is $o(1)$.